# FetchXML Return 0 records while running using C# Console Application

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, console-application, microsoft-dynamics, fetchxml

I've below code snippet when I run this through **FetchXml Tester**, I get one record in result which is correct. But when I run it using C# Console application it return 0 records. Any idea what is missing in code set up?

```
var query = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='true' >"+
"    <entity name='new_paymentplanlist' >"+
"        <attribute name='new_paymentplanlistid' />"+
"        <attribute name='new_event' />"+
"        <link-entity name='new_paymentplankit' from='new_paymentplankitlistid' to='new_paymentplanlistid' link-type='inner' alias='ag' >"+
"            <filter type='and' >"+
"                <condition attribute='new_paymentplankitid' operator='eq' value='"+kitID+"' />"+
"            </filter>"+
"            <link-entity name='new_paymentplan' from='new_paymentplanscheduleid' to='new_paymentplankitid' link-type='inner' alias='ah' >"+
"                <filter type='and' >"+
"                    <condition attribute='new_paymentplanid' operator='eq' value='"+planID+"' />"+
"                </filter>"+
"            </link-entity>"+
"        </link-entity>"+
"    </entity>"+
"</fetch>";

EntityCollection paymentPlanList = service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(query));
if (paymentPlanList.Entities.Count<1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No Payment Plan List found");
                    return;
                }
```

Comment: Do you use same credentials for tests? Do `kitID` and `planID` contain special characters?

Comment: You can debug by commenting the code condition to check which fails to bring the record..